# NestJS undefined dependencies

Tags: node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I'm using `nestjs-i18n` version `8.0.2` on my NestJS project to internationalize the strings.
I have a class in one of my modules that has this constructor:

```
    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(UsersRepository)
        private readonly usersRepository: UsersRepository,
        private readonly apiService: ApiService,
        private readonly i18n: I18nRequestScopeService,
    ) {
    }
```

This is the full class:

```
@QueryHandler(MyQuery)
export class MyQueryHandler implements IQueryHandler<MyQuery> {

    constructor(
        @InjectRepository(UsersRepository)
        private readonly usersRepository: UsersRepository,
        private readonly apiService: ApiService,
        private readonly i18n: I18nRequestScopeService,
    ) {
    }

    async execute(query: MyQuery): Promise<MyResult> {
        ...
    }
}
```

`QueryHandler` is a decorator from the cqrs library `@nestjs/cqrs` version `6.1.0`, if this can be of any help.

For some reason, my 3 dependencies are undefined if I try to inject `I18nRequestScopeService` as shown, but `usersRepository` and `apiService` are correctly defined if I remove the `I18nRequestScopeService` injection.
No warnings or errors are shown on the log.

I have a custom `ExceptionFilter` with this constructor:

```
    constructor(private readonly i18n: I18nRequestScopeService) {
    }
```

and it works just fine.

In `app.module.ts` I have this:

```
@Module({
    imports: [
        ...
        I18nModule.forRoot({
            fallbackLanguage: 'en',
            parser: I18nJsonParser,
            parserOptions: {
                path: path.join(__dirname, 'i18n/'),
            },
            resolvers: [
                { use: QueryResolver, options: ['lang', 'locale', 'l'] },
                new HeaderResolver(['x-custom-lang']),
                AcceptLanguageResolver,
                new CookieResolver(['lang', 'locale', 'l']),
            ],
        })
    ],
    ...
})
```

I tried googling for the problem, but I had no luck. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show the full class, or at least the `@Injcetable` to past the `constructor`? Usually when you get multiple services as `undefined` you either have a `REQUEST` scoped provider which is messing with the Dependency Injection, or you have a missing `@Injectable()` decorator

Comment: `I18nRequestScopeService` comes from the `nestjs-i18n` library. You can find it here: https://github.com/ToonvanStrijp/nestjs-i18n/blob/master/src/lib/services/i18n-request-scope.service.ts

Comment: What kind of class that uses those three dependencies? Is it a regular provider, or is it an enhancer (filter, guard, pipe, or interceptor)?

Comment: It's a cqrs `@QueryHandler`, which leads me to believe that it's a regular provider. I edited the question with the full class and the cqrs library that I'm using

Comment: That explains it. `@QueryHandler()` cannot be request scoped. [More information here](https://github.com/nestjs/cqrs/issues/60)

Comment: Ah, I didn't know this. Could you write this in an answer, so I can mark it as resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Nest's implementation of CQRS does not allow for scoped providers. [There is an open issue about it here](https://github.com/nestjs/cqrs/issues/60)