# NestJS CQRS: (Repository's) Dependency Injection not working in handler

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, cqrs

I am new to nodejs and am trying to implement [NestJS's CQRS 'recipe'](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/cqrs). I have a service with `Request` scope with `QueryBus` injection:

```
@Injectable({scope: Scope.REQUEST})
export class CustomerService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(REQUEST) private readonly req: Request,
    private readonly queryBus: QueryBus,
  ) {}
```

I have defined a handler class `CustomerHandler` to handle `CustomerQuery`:

```
@QueryHandler(CustomerQuery)
export class CustomerHandler implements IQueryHandler<CustomerQuery> {
  constructor(
    private readonly repository: CustomerRepository,
  ) {}

  async execute(query: CustomerQuery) {
    const {response, id, name} = query;
    this.repository.getCustomer(response, id, name);
  }
```

But upon execution I got an error message:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCustomer' of undefined at CustomerHandler.execute
```

which means, if I am not wrong, repository injection failed. (which caused code to fail for statement `this.repository.getCustomer(response, id, name);`)

I have added my repository class `CustomerRepository` in `providers` array of my module `CustomerModule`:

```
@Module({
  imports: [Logger, CqrsModule],
  providers: [CustomerService, ...QueryHandlers, CustomerRepository],
  exports: [CustomerService],
})
export class CustomerModule {}
```

Here's my repository class, for reference:

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomerRepository {
  constructor(
    @Inject(REQUEST) private readonly req: Request,
  ) {}
```

Am I missing something here? Why is my repository class not being instantiated, if thats not the case, why is the repository injection failing in handler. Any input would be appreciated :)

Documentaion I am following: https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/cqrs

Github example I referred: https://github.com/kamilmysliwiec/nest-cqrs-example

**EDIT:**

Handler (`CustomerHandler`) is not able to perform any sort of injection. I tried injecting logger (`PinoLogger`), which led to similar issue. So, it looks like, the problem is not with `CustomerRepository`, but with `CustomerHandler`.

**UPDATE:**

> So basically, the problem is that every CqrsModule provider is
> statically scoped which mean that they cannot depend on request-scoped
> providers. Once you define your command handler as a request-scoped
> provider, either CommandBus or QueryBus won't be able to reference it.
> This is not an issue, but rather a design decision that sits behind
> the entire module.

Source: https://github.com/nestjs/cqrs/issues/60#issuecomment-483288297

i.e. `@QueryHandler()` cannot be request scoped (source: comment on question - [NestJS undefined dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61906755/nestjs-undefined-dependencies) and answer to the same https://stackoverflow.com/a/61916353/10011503).

And, this is also an [open issue](https://github.com/nestjs/cqrs/issues/60).

Comment: `@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST }) export class CustomerRepository {}` https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes#injection-scopes

Comment: Hi @MicaelLevi, Thank you for the suggestion, I tried changing the scope, but the issue still persist.

Comment: try adding an Injectable Decorator in CustomerHandler and add the handler to providers?

Comment: Hi @ShahriarShojib, tried using the decorator as well, with and without scope, but still causing error.

Comment: If all has failed, try injecting it using Inject decorator with or without lazy function

Comment: can you show `QueryHandlers` list?

Comment: @MicaelLevi, @ ShahriarShojib, I just found an answer stating 'Nest's implementation of CQRS does not allow for scoped providers'- https://stackoverflow.com/a/61916353/10011503.

There's also an open issue for the same - https://github.com/nestjs/cqrs/issues/60 (got the link from same answer and comments on the question)

Comment: @MicaelLevi, here's `QueryHandlers` list - `export const QueryHandlers = [CustomerHandler];`

Answer (score 1):

Reading nestjs doc, i saw that all handlers for command and query handlers are resolve en default scope, so, all dependencies with request or trasient scope are not provide in handlers. Solution is inject factory objects that resolve dependencies when are necesary

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).